# How to run selenium webdriver test cases from command line without testng/maven

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cmd

I am writing test cases using selenium webdriver.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");// Open the URL.
driver.manage().window().maximize(); // Maximize the window
driver.quit();
```

Now I want to run this test from command line and create a batch file. I am not using any testng or maven. How can I run from cmd?

Answer (score 4):

Create a new Java project in your favorite IDE platform (Eclipse, Netbeans, Intellij ...).
Download and unpack Selenium Java language bindings from here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

It contains all required libraries (jar files) and also Firefox driver.
Add all libraries (jar files) to your project to the classpath. Don't forget to add also all jar files from `lib` subdirectory. 
Refer to documentation of your IDE to know how to do it.
You can also configure your project as maven project and let Maven download all dependecies for you, this is a dependency definition from Selenium project page: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Next create java class with `main` function:

```
package mypackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class MySeleniumTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");// Maximize the window.
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        try {
        // wait 4 seconds before closing the browser
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

You can then run this class in the IDE to test if it woks - before saving it to a runnable jar file.

---

Next build the project, and then export it to a runnable jar file - refer to your IDE documentation to know how to do it (in Eclipse click options: File/Export/Java/Runnable JAR file, choose the option "Package required libraries into generated JAR").

---

And finally open a command prompt, change a current directory to the directory when the generated jar has been saved, and run it using:

```
java -jar name_of_jar_file.jar
```

Comment: But how can I create jar file using cmd without using any IDE?

Comment: Follow a Oracle's tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html  Just `jar cf jar-file-name input-file-list (or *)`

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I am getting error while compiling to class as below : error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist. I am using the command javac -cp .;*.jar Demo.java . Where *.jar contains all the jar file for selenium webdriver

Comment: There are missing libraries in the classpath. Quick fix: copy all Selenium libraries to a subdirectory, and specify a name of this directory in the classpath: `java -jar -cp name_of_lib_subdirectory myJar.jar`.Unfortunately I don't know how to correctly package libraries into the jar by hand using `jar`, I haven't done it for years, I prefer tools (Maven, IDE, etc), Probably you need to create a manifest file and include it in the jar file.