# Java Selenium Webdriver Connection Refused

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, connection-refused

I am getting the all too common connection refused error on my selenium webdriver.  The same code was executing a few weeks ago.

I have been reading in circles through existing posts and have tried updating geckodriver and FireFox to no avail.  I can run the same code on another computer running the same versions of the driver, browser and libraries etc. How can I find the cause specific to this machine?  the error is below.

Debug 1 
Debug 2 
Debug 3

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:28379 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host: 'LT9LTDRC2', ip: '10.130.3.15', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131' Driver info: driver.version: Gecko_Driver  
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)  
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)     
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)    
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)    
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)  
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:108)     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:137)     at seleniumPrograms.Gecko_Driver.main(Gecko_Driver.java:13) 
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:28379 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect   
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)  
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)    
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)    
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)  
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)   at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)    
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)     
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)     
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:139)  
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:87)   
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:343)   
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)   
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)     
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)  ... 8 more 
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect   
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)  
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)   
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)    
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)     
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)     
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)     
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)  
at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)     
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)  ... 23 more
```

And I get this running even the following basic code.

```
enter code here
package seleniumPrograms;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

    public class Gecko_Driver {
        public static void main(String[] args)  {
             System.out.println("Debug 1");
             DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
             System.out.println("Debug 2");
             capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
             System.out.println("Debug 3");
             WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
             System.out.println("Debug 4");
             driver.get("http://www.google.com");

             driver.manage().window().maximize();  
             driver.quit();
        }
 }
```

Example with chrome.

```
@Test
        public void testGoogleSearch() throws InterruptedException {
          // Optional, if not specified, WebDriver will search your path for chromedriver.
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get("http://www.google.com/xhtml");
          Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
          WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
          searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
          searchBox.submit();
          Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
          driver.quit();
        }
```

Failure trace:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'LT9LTDRC2', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
>   Driver info: driver.version: Gecko_Driver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:193)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:181)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:184)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:171)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:124)
>       at seleniumPrograms.Gecko_Driver.testGoogleSearch(Gecko_Driver.java:16)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:31675/status] to be available after 20002 ms
>       at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:107)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:190)
>       ... 33 more
>   Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:140)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:80)
>       ... 34 more
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:128)
>       ... 35 more

Comment: I got `connection refused` on Linux.  I just rebooted; fixed.  But, I have a very slow hard drive, need more RAM, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our security dept introduced a policy which blocked access to the execution of the geckodriver.exe. This was identified by attempting to run from cmd. Not sure why I didn't get the meaningful error in the IDE (blocked by group policy) for gecko, I did get this error for chrome and IE.  In order to use the driver it needed to be saved in Program files though this may be specific to my situation.  If you get this error for Geckodriver i would suggest trying to execute it from cmd to see if there is a policy issue.

Comment: Can you provide details on how to execute it from cmd?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225903/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-from-command-line-without-testng-maven

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your Question:

I don't see any error as such in your code but the error stack trace `HttpHostConnectException` says it all.

Perform the following steps:

1. I don't see any necessity to use `throws InterruptedException`, you may consider to remove it.
2. As per best practices try to keep the geckodriver in convenient locations: e.g. `C:\\your_directory`.
3. Avoid using directory names with `Temp`.
4. Though you have taken help of `DesiredCapabilities` Class, you haven't passed it while you initiated the driver instance. You must be doing:

   ```
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
   ```
5. Clear your Mozilla Firefox Browser cache.
6. From the Windows Task Manager, manually kill all the running instances of geckodriver.exe
7. You may require to run the CCleaner to keep off all the unwanted stuff.
8. Restart you machine.
9. Execute your Test. It should work well.
10. At the end of your Test Step do call `driver.quit()` to prevent geckodriver instances from dangling.
11. Here is your own working code block adding the `System.setProperty` line:

    ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
    System.out.println("Debug 1");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    System.out.println("Debug 2");
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
    System.out.println("Debug 3");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    System.out.println("Debug 4");
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();  
    driver.quit();
    ```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Dev but unfortunately after completing all the suggested steps I still get the same error.

Comment: Still no change unfortunately.  I have geckodriver set in environment variables so I don't need to have this set there at all.

Comment: Update your current code & the error stacktrace in the Question area for further analysis please. Thanks

Comment: Done.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @JamesBowman Seems gecko's Marionette is not getting hooked, so I think you should consider be very specific about which variant of webdriver you intend to use among geckodriver, chromedriver & ie. So you may consider adding the `System.setProperty` line as per my updated code block.

Comment: Thanks Dev I really appreciate your help however the suggestions have not resolved the issue.  As I stated initially I can execute the code on another machine with no issue.  The geckodriver is being connected to by both approaches, Environment Variable or by setting the system property. If i remove the line and the variable I get an informative error.  I believe it is something on my system as previously I have had success on this pc and now it has started refusing.    I will edit and add an attempt with chrome. perhaps the error log will add more info.

Comment: Starting to suspect we may have had some group policy changes on our network recently.  Trying to execute gecko driver from cmd i get "This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator."

Comment: I have managed to progress from this error (to another).  Our security dept did introduce a policy which blocked access to the execution of the geckodriver.exe.  This was identified by attempting to run from cmd.  Not sure why I didn't get the meaningful error in the IDE (blocked by group policy) for gecko, I did for chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error here. After a system reboot, the code worked just fine.
My problem was that my code left some processes open at the end, and they were using a lot of RAM.
Try running:

```
pkill geckodriver
pkill firefox
pkill selenium
```

And then run your code again.