# Firefox Path error? org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Failed to start browser

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I have read the similar question on SO however no answer was posted in addition my error does seem to be different in detail.

When I run

```
package seleniumPrograms;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class Gecko_Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Program 
        Files\\Drivers\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();  
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

I'm Getting following Error :

> 1495603278185  geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:25555
>   1495603278690 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser
>   \?\C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args
>   ["-marionette"] Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Failed to start
>   browser \?\C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe: other os
>   error Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time:
>   'unknown' System info: host: 'LT9LTDRC2', ip: '172.22.1.111', os.name:
>   'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_131' Driver info: driver.version: Gecko_Driver remote
>   stacktrace: stack backtrace:    0:           0x489f6f - 
>   1:           0x48ad59 -     2:           0x43a15d - 
>   3:           0x43f982 -     4:           0x443f9a - 
>   5:           0x41ddb1 -     6:           0x4091c7 - 
>   7:           0x6bc939 -     8:           0x415a19 - 
>   9:           0x6b6e43 -    10:     0x7ff9512c8364 -
>   BaseThreadInitThunk   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$22(ProtocolHandshake.java:365)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:368)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
>     at seleniumPrograms.Gecko_Driver.main(Gecko_Driver.java:13)

I am running on `Selenium 3.4.0`, `Gecko 0.16.1` and `FF 53.0.3` so I don't think its a version issue.  I am guessing it could be the `\\?\C` section where it is looking for the browser.

Comment: can you remove these `        DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);` and try

Comment: Duplicate of OP's own Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060582/java-selenium-webdriver-connection-refused where OP is aware `Our security dept introduced a policy which blocked access to the execution of the geckodriver.exe. This was identified by attempting to run from cmd. Not sure why I didn't get the meaningful error in the IDE (blocked by group policy) for gecko, I did get this error for chrome and IE. In order to use the driver it needed to be saved in Program files though this may be specific to my situation.`

Comment: Thanks @TrimantraSoftwareSolution I tried your solution but the outcome was the same.  Dev this issue is different even though the same code causes it.  The error log is different. Previously I needed to save the webdriver in a particular directory to avoid a connection refused error.  This is a failed to start browser error which occurs after the webdriver starts listening.   Had I known to check via command line for a group policy error with my previous issue it would have saved me a lot of time. This is why I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since this problem has been reported, but it would be good to get it finally answered. Basically what was happening here was a bug in geckodriver, which I fixed for the 0.17 release. So specifically this failure should not be present anymore since this version got released.