# Javascript Selenium Internet Explorer 11 Options

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, internet-explorer-11

I currently have my selenium **javascript** test set up with the chromedriver configuration below:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('..');    
const  webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
```

I followed the instructions that tell you to insert the IEDriverServer.exe in your PATH which I have done and confirmed it is the correct location and file naem.  I have also added in the DWORD registry as the same tutorial tells me. All my configuration is correct but I think I am making some assumptions about how things are run with chrome vs. internet explorer.

Here's what I'm doing to run my IE Test, please correct me if I am wrong: 
new configuration code: 
    const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('..');

```
const  webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('internet explorer').build();
```

1. Start Selenium Server java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar in command prompt
2. Start IEDriverServer.exe in another window by double clicking the  .exe file
3. In a 3rd command prompt window, cd to my folder where my tests and drivers are located and run the test using "node test2.js"

I  get the following error message:

```
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:60381
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (<file path omitted>\index.js:244:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: possibly a firewall issue. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060582/java-selenium-webdriver-connection-refused) for other solutions.

Comment: I had a firewall prompt for both the iedriverserver and the selenium server and I accepted them both. I don't know what else needs to go through the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, I use firefox, chrome, ie. But capabilities doesn't want to be applied and it seems that they don't work.

```
var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");

var DriverFactory = {
    create: function (browser) {
        if (browser == "ie" || browser == "internet explorer") {
            let capabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.ie();
            capabilities.set("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
            capabilities.set("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
            return driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(capabilities).build();
        } else {
            return driver = new webdriver
                .Builder().forBrowser(browser)
                .build();
        }
    }
}
module.exports = DriverFactory;
```

then just import the module, and call it

```
async function () {
    driver = await DriverFactory.create("firefox");
};
```