# org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: connection refused error while running headless firefox browser in Ubuntu using AutoCloseable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, tomcat9

Error:

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: connection refused
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
> System info: host: 'ubuntu', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-112-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_252'
> Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Code:

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/usr/bin/geckodriver");
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setHeadless(true);

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF);
System.out.println(1);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
// code does not reach this point. Look like its freezing at the initialisation of 'driver'.
try (AutoCloseable autoCloseable = () -> driver.close()) {
         ...
```

I have changed Java Version as another question recommended (from 11 to 8).

EDIT: That post ([Java Selenium Webdriver Connection Refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060582/java-selenium-webdriver-connection-refused)) did not work.

EDIT #2: I am running it through Tomcat 9.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any such issue with your code block. I took your code and executed with the following configuration:

- *OS*: [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10)
- [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8): [JDK 8u251](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
- [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491): Latest stable version *3.141.59*
- [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403): [GeckoDriver v0.26.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0)
- *Firefox*: Latest stable version *79.0*

---

### Execution details

Here are the execution details using [autocloseable](/questions/tagged/autocloseable):

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.util.logging.Level;

  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  //import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriverLogLevel;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

  public class AutoCloseableSelenium {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
          options.setHeadless(true);
          //options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE);
          java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF);
          System.out.println(1);
          FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
          try (AutoCloseable autoCloseable = () -> driver.quit()) { }
          System.out.println("Exiting program");
    }
  ```

  }
- Console Output:

  ```
  1
  1595977246813 mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\SOMABH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile345iC4"
  *** You are running in headless mode.
  JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
  console.error: SearchCache: "_readCacheFile: Error reading cache file:" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
  1595977254325 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 53331
  1595977254676 Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
  1595977254896 Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 53331
  JavaScript error: resource://activity-stream/lib/ActivityStreamPrefs.jsm, line 27: NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIPrefBranch.removeObserver]
  console.warn: services.settings: main/messaging-experiments sync interrupted by shutdown
  JavaScript error: resource://services-settings/IDBHelpers.jsm, line 24: Error: IndexedDB: main/fxmonitor-breaches list() IndexedDB:  execute() The application is shutting down
  JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/Sqlite.jsm, line 928: Error: Connection is not open.
  Exiting program
  ```

Comment: if it means anything I am running this through a tomcat web app.

Comment: @user12346306 You didn't tell us about your binary configurations.

Comment: I don't understand what 'binary configurations' are, can you elaborate?